# 'List' object is not callable

Tags: python, sorting, search

I have a program for an assignment that makes a list of integers from a text file. It then sorts the data with either insertion or bubble sort. I chose bubble sort. I may switch if necessary but they are both O(n^2)(I believe). The integers represent distances on a street. The goal is to calculate the best location to open up a new store via finding the median of the list. However, when I run what I have so far, I get an error that says the 'list' object is not callable. I do not understand this error.

```
def make_list(perkList,fileName):


    with open(fileName) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.split()
            perkList.append(int(line[1]))# reason for this is there is a string in line[0]
    return perkList


def perkSort(perkList):

    sorted = False
    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(len(perkList)-1):
            if perkList[i] > perkList[i+1]:
                sorted = False
                perkList[i], perkList[i+1] = perkList[i+1], perkList[i]
    print("sorted List",perkList)




def median(perkList):
    middle = len(perkList)//2
    if middle % 2 == 0:
        return (perkList(middle) + perkList(middle - 1))//2
    else:
        return perkList(middle)
def main()
    perkList = []
    fileName = input("Enter file name: ")
    make_list(perkList,fileName)
    print(perkList)
    perkSort(perkList)
    median(perkList)
main()
```

my list is [70, 120, 170, 200]

`Traceback (most recent call last):
sorted List [70, 120, 170, 200]
  File "C:/Users/User'/PycharmProjects/messes/findSlow.py", line 43, in <module>
    median(perkList)
  File "C:/Users/User'/PycharmProjects/messes/findSlow.py", line 34, in median
    return (perkList(middle) + perkList(middle - 1))//2
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: I realize this is not the best way to ask this question. I will try my best to clear any confusion.

Comment: Can you show us the `traceback`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
perkList(middle)
```

You need this:

```
perkList[middle]
```

Comment: Damn I feel dumb now. Thank you though :)